# How to raise the next increment for customer_id.entity_id in database

Tags: customer, database

To summarize, I'm attempting to merge two Magento installs. I have a series of customers that I'm trying to incorporate from one instance into another.

With that being said... I would like customer IDs to start at a higher number. To proceed with this, I created a test account and went into the Magento database to see the newest customer_id.entity_id to be 12910. I increased the customer ID by 2000 to make it 14910. I then went back into my store and proceeded to create another test account but after going back to Magento I see that it is 12911 and not 14911. I thought, "maybe I need to clear cache or reindex". Did that, created *another* account and it was 12912.

So I'm guessing Magento doesn't create customer IDs by adding 1 to the greatest entity_id. How would I successfully increase my increment in customer_entity.entity_id so that the next customer to create an account would see 14911? Another way to say it: How would I manually set what the next entity_id would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find it after extensive searching. Let's say you want to start at 300001..

```
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = 300001;
```

That's it!

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440755/how-to-start-with-a-different-customer-id-in-magento#sthash.QoZZN3SD.dpuf

http://www.magetricks.com/tricks/how-to-start-with-a-different-customer-id

Comment: I can't accept for another day. I answered two of my own questions this week and SO assumes I'm trying to rack up points. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdhts38purglzdx/Screenshot%202014-12-06%2009.54.46.png?dl=0